# failed to install php-process extension

Tags: php, linux, centos, yum

In Centos6.5 and php56, I install php-process(which include posix and pcntl extension) successfully.

```
[root@iZ94fgh1ehiZ etc]# yum install php56-php-process --enablerepo=remi
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
Package php56-php-process-5.6.17-1.el6.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

But I just can't use the posix extension in php-cli or in php-fpm(I have restart php-fpm, and there's no posix in phpinfo page)

Answer (score 2):

I find that yum failed to add posix.so into /etc/php.d/posix.ini, and the posix.so is located in /opt/remi/php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/posix.so...

This is because I install PHP5.4 and PHP5.6 at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want posix extension as base package, you need to install "php-process"

If you want posix extension as SCL package (parallel installation), you need to install php56-php-process.